# word problem equal angles between two segments of the same triangle

Tags: geometry

A statue is 50 feet high and stands on a pedestal 25 feet high
How far back should an observer with eyes 5 feet above the ground stand in order to have equal angles made at her eyes between the statue and the pedestal on which it sits ?

Answer (score 3):

By using the Triangle Angle Bisector Theorem and pythagorean theorem, the observer distance is $40m$ away from the statue.
[image]

Comment: wow no law of sines needed!! :) I knew there was an easier way to attack this problem which im sure is common to engineering . thanks a million ! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution**

The following identity will be used in what follows:

$$\tan(\alpha\pm\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)\pm\tan(\beta)}{1\mp\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}.\tag 1$$

Now, consider the following figure
[image]

We wish to have $$\tau+\epsilon=\mu-\tau$$

and we have that

$$\tan(\tau)=\frac4x,\ \tan(\varepsilon)=\frac1x,\ \tan(\mu)=\frac{14}x.$$

From $(1)$

$$\tan(\tau+\varepsilon)=\frac{\frac4x+\frac1x}{1-\frac4{x^2}}=\frac{5x}{x^2-4}\tag 2$$
and

$$\tan(\mu-\tau)=\frac{\frac{14}x-\frac4x}{1+\frac{56}{x^2}}=\frac{10x}{x^2+56}.\tag 3$$

According to our wish $(2)$ and $(3)$ yield $$\pm 8$$

But $1$ of our units equals $5$ original units. So, the result is $$\pm40.$$